# Uniform Circular Motion and Work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, work

I was usually told that in a uniform circular motion the work is 0 because the force is every instant perpendicular to the displacement. However, studying the motion i noticed that there is a force acting on the moving object that is always parallel to the displacement and perpendicular to the radius to the circumference ( it's the force that continuously changes the velocity vector).
Why it doesn't do work ?

[image]

Comment: What you have labeled F in the diagram is not a force, it is a velocity.

Comment: See [Work in circular motions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90947)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force is not tangential. It is always radially inward.

Thus, it is perpendicular to the velocity vector and does no work.

[image]

(Image source : Wikipedia)

Note that the **direction of force** in this image is in radially inward direction, i.e. exactly opposite to the radius vector.

Comment: However, if the velocity vector constantly changes shouldn't there be a force ?

Comment: @Koinos The force (not shown in figure) is in radially inward direction